# How can I force NonlinearModelFit to converge for a complicated fit function if I have good initial estimates?

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to fit a fairly complicated numerical function that is made up of matrix operations and recursive functions, so it does not have a nice closed form. I have narrowed down a workable range of fitting parameters that result in a function looking like my (sparse) data.

```
t = Range[150, 650,5];
p1 = ListLinePlot[
   Transpose[{trange, 
     Table[FitFunc[t, 5*10^3, 5*10^3, 5*10^6, 100, 40], {t, trange}]}]]; 
p2 = ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {marker, 0.07}]; 
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

But for some reason the fitting procedure always hangs. I've tried to reduce the maximum iterations, only fitting to one parameter, and also applying constraints within a range I think will work.

```
model = FitFunc[t, 5*10^3, 5*10^3, X, 100, 40];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, model, {{X, 5*10^6}}, t, MaxIterations -> 5]
```

When I use the expression below with a constraint, I get an error that states `Method -> Automatic can only be used for unconstrained problems.`, but I get that error no matter what method I use.

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, {model, {X > 10^6 && X < 10^7}}, {{X, 5*10^6}}, t, MaxIterations -> 5]
```

How can I force the model to converge? Eventually, I will need to fit 4 or 5 parameters. Is my model over-constrained? Am I using `NonlinearModelFit` incorrectly?

Edit: here's a simplified version of my code.

```
jinter = 3; 
jbulk = 4; 
jf = 5; 
ϕbulk = 0; 
Modsq[z_] := ComplexExpand[Re[z]]^2 + ComplexExpand[Im[z]]^2; 
χc[A_, ϕ_] := A*Exp[(I*ϕ*Pi)/180]; 
χh[j_, χinter_, χbulk_, ϕinter_] := If[j == jinter, χc[χinter, ϕinter], 
   If[j == jbulk, χc[χbulk, ϕbulk], ToExpression[StringJoin["χ", ToString[j]]]]]
ξh[j_, d_] := If[j == jbulk, d, ToExpression[StringJoin["ξ", ToString[j]]]]; 
fh[w_String, o_String] := ToExpression[StringJoin[w, o]]
xlim[j_, d_] := Sum[If[i == jbulk, d, ToExpression[StringJoin["ξ", ToString[i]]]], {i, 1, j}]
λ0 = 1550; 
θ0 = (40*Pi)/180; 
ϵ0 = 1; 
nω = {1.00027398, 4.01 + 0.125*I, 3.243 + 0.*I, 3.243 + 0.*I, 4.01 + 0.125*I}; 
nΩ = {1.00027821, 4.5068 + 0.41586*I, 3.479 + 0.008*I, 3.479 + 0.008*I, 4.5068 + 0.41586*I}; 
χ1 = 0; 
χ2 = 837; 
ξ1 = 0; 
ξ2 = 10; 
ξ3 = 1; 
θω[y_ /; 2 <= y <= jf] := ArcSin[(nω[[y - 1]]*Sin[θω[y - 1]])/nω[[y]]]; 
θω[1] := θ0; 
θΩ[y_ /; 3 <= y <= jf] := ArcSin[(nΩ[[y - 1]]*Sin[θΩ[y - 1]])/nΩ[[y]]]; 
θΩ[1] := ArcSin[(nΩ[[2]]*Sin[θΩ[2]])/nΩ[[1]]]; 
θΩ[2] := ArcSin[(nω[[1]]*Sin[θω[1]])/nΩ[[2]]]; 
rω[i_, j_] := (nω[[j]]*Cos[θω[i]] - nω[[i]]*Cos[θω[j]])/(nω[[j]]*Cos[θω[i]] + nω[[i]]*Cos[θω[j]]); 
rΩ[i_, j_] := (nΩ[[i]]*Cos[θΩ[j]] - nΩ[[j]]*Cos[θΩ[i]])/(nΩ[[i]]*Cos[θΩ[j]] + nΩ[[j]]*Cos[θΩ[i]]); 
rσ[i_, j_] := (nΩ[[j]]*Cos[θω[i]] - nω[[i]]*Cos[θΩ[j]])/(nΩ[[j]]*Cos[θω[i]] + nω[[i]]*Cos[θΩ[j]]); 
tω[i_, j_] := (2*nω[[i]]*Cos[θω[i]])/(nω[[j]]*Cos[θω[i]] + nω[[i]]*Cos[θω[j]]); 
tΩ[i_, j_] := (2*nΩ[[i]]*Cos[θΩ[i]])/(nΩ[[j]]*Cos[θΩ[i]] + nΩ[[i]]*Cos[θΩ[j]]); 
tσ[i_, j_] := (2*nΩ[[j]]*Cos[θΩ[j]])/(nΩ[[j]]*Cos[θω[i]] + nω[[i]]*Cos[θΩ[j]]); 
k0 = (2*Pi)/λ0; 
κ[j_, o_String] := Switch[o, "ω", k0, "Ω", 2*k0, "σ", 2*k0]; 
ϵ[j_, o_String] := Switch[o, "ω", nω[[j]]^2, "Ω", nΩ[[j]]^2, "σ", nω[[j]]^2]
NN[j_, o_String] := Switch[o, "ω", nω[[j]]*Cos[θω[j]], "Ω", nΩ[[j]]*Cos[θΩ[j]], "σ", nω[[j]]*Cos[θω[j]]]; 
M[i_, j_, o_String] := {{1, fh["r", o][i, j]}, {fh["r", o][i, j], 1}}/fh["t", o][i, j]; 
ϕ[j_, o_String, z_] := Exp[I*NN[j, o]*κ[j, o]*z]; 
Φ[j_, o_String, z_] := If[j == 1, IdentityMatrix[2], {{ϕ[j, o, z], 0}, {0, 1/ϕ[j, o, z]}}]; 
T[f_, d_] := Module[{τ, x}, τ = M[2, 1, "ω"]; For[x = 3, x < f + 1, x++, 
      τ = M[x, x - 1, "ω"] . Φ[x - 1, "ω", ξh[x - 1, d]] . τ]; Return[τ]]; 
ReflC[f_, d_] := -(T[f, d][[2,1]]/T[f, d][[2,2]]); 
Ε[j_, d_] := 2*T[j, d] . {{1, 0}, {0, 1}} . {{1}, {ReflC[jf, d]}}; 
L[j_, d_] := Module[{λ, x}, If[j == 1, λ = IdentityMatrix[2], λ = M[2, 1, "Ω"]]; 
     For[x = 3, x < j + 1, x++, λ = M[x, x - 1, "Ω"] . Φ[x - 1, "Ω", ξh[x, d]] . λ]; Return[λ]]; 
R[j_, d_] := Module[{ρ, x}, ρ = IdentityMatrix[2]; For[x = jf - 1, x >= j, x--, 
      ρ = Inverse[Φ[x, "Ω", ξh[x, d]]] . M[x, x + 1, "Ω"] . ρ]; Return[ρ]]; 
Tbar[j_, d_] := Inverse[L[j, d]] . R[j, d]; 
px[j_, z_, d_, χinter_, χbulk_, ϕinter_] := 4*ϵ0*χh[j, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter]*Sin[Pi/4]*Cos[Pi/4]*Sin[θω[j]]*
    Cos[θω[j]]*((Φ[j, "ω", z] . Ε[j, d])^2 + (2*Ε[j, d][[1,1]]*Ε[j, d][[2,1]])*{{1}, {1}}); 
pz[j_, z_, d_, χinter_, χbulk_, ϕinter_] := 2*ϵ0*χh[j, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter]*Sin[Pi/4]*Cos[Pi/4]*
    Sin[θω[j]]^2*((Φ[j, "ω", z] . Ε[j, d])^2 + (2*Ε[j, d][[1,1]]*Ε[j, d][[2,1]])*{{1}, {1}}); 
Εσ[j_, z_, d_, χinter_, χbulk_, ϕinter_] := 
   ((4*Pi*ϵ0)*(pz[j, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter] + px[j, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter]))/
     (ϵ[j, "ω"] - ϵ[j, "Ω"]) - ((4*Pi*ϵ0)*(pz[j, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter] - 
       px[j, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter]))/ϵ[j, "Ω"]; 
Σ[j_, z_, d_, χinter_, χbulk_, ϕinter_] := Switch[j, 1, M[1, 2, "σ"] . Εσ[j, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕ], jf, 
    -M[jf - 1, jf, "σ"] . Εσ[jf, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter], _, 
    (Inverse[Φ[j, "Ω", ξh[j, d]]] . M[j - 1, j, "σ"] . Φ[j, "σ", ξh[j, d]] - M[j - 1, j, "σ"]) . 
     Εσ[j, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter]]; 
Σp[j_, z_, d_, χinter_, χbulk_, ϕinter_] := Inverse[L[j, d]] . Σ[j, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter]
F[j_, z_, d_, χinter_, χbulk_, ϕinter_] := {{1, 0}, {Tbar[j, d][[2,1]], -Tbar[j, d][[1,1]]}} . 
     Σp[j, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter]/Tbar[j, d][[1,1]]; 
Esum[d_, χinter_, χbulk_, ϕinter_] := 
  Modsq[Sum[Integrate[F[i, z, d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter][[1]], {z, xlim[i - 1, d], xlim[i, d]}], {i, 2, jf - 1}]][[1]]
FitFunc[d_, a_, b_, χinter_, χbulk_, ϕinter_] := a*Esum[d, χinter, χbulk, ϕinter] + b; 
marker = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}]; 
data = {{250., 80327.5}, {264., 142193.}, {290., 305720.}, {298., 338993.}, {310., 335892.}, {400., 217848.}, 
   {560., 608853.}, {616., 615713.}}
trange = Range[150, 650, 5]; 
p1 = ListLinePlot[Transpose[{trange, Table[FitFunc[t, 5/10^4, 5*10^3, 5*10^6, 100, 40], {t, trange}]}]]; 
p2 = ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {marker, 0.07}]; 
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

Comment: I don't see how you can expect an answer if you don't provide a definition of `FitFunc`.

Comment: @JimB It does not have a closed form because the subfunctions that make it up are recursive and output 2x2 matrices. If I tried to write it all out here, I'd run out of characters to type. `FitFunc` picks one element of the final 2x2 matrix. I can try to describe the fitting parameters in `FitFunc[t, a, b, X, c, d]`: `a` is a scaling constant, `b` is a vertical offset, `c` has the same units as parameter as `X`, but differs by about 5 orders of magnitude, and `d` is a phase.

Comment: I understand it doesn't have a closed-form.  But unless one can plug in values for the parameters and get predictions, I don't see much that can be offered here other than maybe the following:  (1) use `Method -> "NMinimize"` which seems more stable/forgiving, (2) Scaling the parameters so that they are on the same order of magnitude, etc.

Comment: @user66091 We normally need a **minimal working example** of Mathematica code that actually runs or reproduces the error that causes the problem. Otherwise, you are asking us to speculate, which is not fair.

Comment: @rhermans I understand your point. I'll try to make a simplified version of it that's easier to share here, or upload it somewhere that you can access.

Comment: @JimB Just a heads up, I edited the post and included some simplified code that should work

Comment: If you wait long enough (something less than 2 hours as I came back to my computer and found it done - don't know when it really finished), the following works:  `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  FitFunc[t, a, b, \[Chi]inter, \[Chi]bulk, \[Phi]inter], {a, 
   b, \[Chi]inter, \[Chi]bulk, \[Phi]inter}, t, Method -> "NMinimize"]`.

Comment: It only took 3 minutes.

Comment: Ok, mine works now as well but it took about 30-45 minutes. Plotting the fitted model took another while. Thanks for the help!